# Nginx - workers connection metric

Tags: nginx, metrics

We have some issues with workers connection in Nginx. We need to monitor and alert them, this is why i am looking for metrics.

I found Nginx Amplify to allow workers connections, the problem is that Amplify sends data to external server (after login https://amplify.nginx.com/, you have own dashboard to monitor systems/agents).

Do you know if there is any other way to monitor nginx workers connections, which is not sending data for external servers ?

Thanks in advance.